# System.AccessViolationException with a regular file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I get the exception on this code :
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Project4.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

but it is not a protected file or read only!!! ,and when i use a text file the error disappears

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct student{
    string name;
    int age;
};

int main(){
    student s1, s2, s3;
    s1.name = "basel";
    s1.age = 20;
    ofstream in;
    in.open("example.std" ,ios::binary);
    in.write((char*)&s1, sizeof(s1));
    in.close();
    ifstream out;
    out.open("example.std" ,ios::binary);
    out.read((char*)&s2, sizeof(s2));
    cout << s2.name;
    return 0;
}
```

anyone can help!!!

Comment: 'System.AccessViolationException' is an C++/clr exception (you might adjust your project settings)

Comment: .. and it's not referring to file i/o, but mot likely to memory access within your process (as stated in the description of the error you're probably attempting to write, or read, to or from an invalid memory region)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're trying to store the struct into file and read it back, as you struct declaration:

```
struct student{
    string name;
    int age;
};
```

As suggested by your code, you also want to store the content of the string "name", but

```
in.write((char*)&s1, sizeof(s1));
```

won't write the content of the string to the file as std::string internal holds a pointer to the content, you're only writing the value of the pointer to the file.  Thus, when you read it backup, you get memory errors.

To archive what you want, you cloud use the a char array with fixed size in the struct.

Comment: thank you it worked correctly after changing name to char* ^_^ @Matt

Comment: is there a way to do it using string? @Matt

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment, the exception is thrown because you are attempting to write, or read, to or from an invalid memory location.

The most likely culprit in your case would be:

```
out.read((char*)&s2, sizeof(s2));
```

Have you tried to step through the code with the debugger? Which line does it fault on?

You are trying to serialize, and then deserialize, the struct to a file. But almost certainly there are some alignment problems which are causing the problems (and the fact that the name member is a pointer to another data structure)

You could modify your code to serialize the contents of the struct, member by member, and then deserialize in a similar fashion:

```
// Serialize 
ofstream out;
out.open("example.std", ios::binary);
out.write(s1.name.c_str(), sizeof(char)*s1.name.size());
out.write((char*)&s1.age, sizeof(int));
out.close();
```

Now comes the tricky part: deserialization. How do you know how long the string is? Should you assume the string is as long as the file is, minus the 4-byte integer that is used to store the age?

Comment: the error appears at the end of the program when the debugger reaches return 0 @Mike